# how to get dropdown displayed text?

Tags: reactjs

This element only shows me a number to choose, that means the options 1 or 2. Is there a chance to add a name to that select list?

How can i get the name from the dropdown selected text?

```
export default function App() {
  const handledd = event => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    console.log(event.target.name);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select onChange={handledd} id="cars">
        <option>select</option>
        <option value="X$" name="Volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="X5" name="Saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="X6" name="VW">VW</option>
        <option value="X7" name="Audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get the selected text:

```
console.log(event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].text);
```

Or try this to get the selected `name` attribute value:

```
console.log(event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].attributes.name.value)
```

`event.target.name` doesn't work because it's returning the name of the select element and you haven't defined one. For example, if your select tag was this:

```
<select onChange={handledd} name="cars">
```

Then `event.target.name` would be `cars`.

Here's a full working event handler:

```
  const handledd = event => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    console.log(event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].text);
    console.log(
      event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].attributes.name.value
    );
  };
```

Also available here: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-62317749-wp0i7

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT add name to the option list but add name to the select tag.

```
      <select onChange={handledd} name="cars" id="cars">
        <option>select</option>
        <option value="X$">Volvo</option>
        <option value="X5">Saab</option>
        <option value="X6">VW</option>
        <option value="X7">Audi</option>
      </select>
```